# Swift: Cannot convert the expression's type

Tags: swift, core-image, cifilter

I'm trying to write my own CIFilter in Swift. I'm having problems when it comes to the real beef of the class, which is the `outputImage` method:

```
class CustomFilter : CIFilter {
    var kernel: CIKernel

    var inputImage: CIImage
    var color: CIColor
    var threshold: NSNumber

    // ... stuff omitted ...

    func outputImage() -> CIImage {
        let zero = NSNumber(double: 0 as Double)
        let width = NSNumber(double: inputImage.extent().size.width.native as Double)
        let height = NSNumber(double: inputImage.extent().size.height.native as Double)

        let src = CISampler(image: inputImage)
        let arguments  = [src, color, threshold] as [AnyObject]
        let extent = [zero, zero, width, height]

        return self.apply(
            kernel,
            arguments: arguments,
            options: (kCIApplyOptionExtent: extent)
        )
    }
}
```

The compiler error message concerning the last line of the method is as follows:

> Cannot convert the expression's type '(@lvalue CIKernel, arguments:
>   [AnyObject], options: (kCIApplyOptionExtent: [NSNumber]))' to type
>   'CIKernel!'

Can someone with more Swift or Core Image experience please point me in the right direction? I couldn't find an answer even after an hour of trying and googling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets to create the options dictionary:

```
return self.apply(kernel, arguments: arguments, options: [kCIApplyOptionExtent: extent])
```

The required argument is of type `[NSObject : AnyObject]!`

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it must have been something stupid like that! ;)